# When I use count function in my codeigniter it gives me error

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to use count function in CodeIgniter and I am recently updating xampp `7.2` to `7.2.12`

This my code I am trying like this

```
 print_r(count($this->input->post('disp_ch_ids')));
   exit();
```

It gives me this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Warning
>       Message:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
>       Filename: dispatch_challan/DispatchChallanController.php
>       Line Number: 24

Comment: disp_ch_ids is this an array in submitted form. As error is clear count can be used for array or objects

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: according to http://php.net/manual/de/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types - in php 7.2. they added a warning if you dont pass an array or object which implements `Countable`

Comment: sizeOf()  gives me same error @SougataBose

Comment: If you want to count your inputs do this. $all_values = $this->input->post(); And then count($all_values);

Comment: @SougataBose `sizeof` is an alias of `count` so the error will still be thrown. OP, always use `count` but pass an array or and object to it. Dump your input without the `count` to see if it is an array or object.

Comment: ` $temp = $this->input->post('disp_ch_ids');
    print_r(count($temp));` @DanishAli i try like this but gives me same error

Comment: @ShaikhFarhanSultan $this->input->post('disp_ch_ids') is a single value not an array. I said to you $this->input->post(). Do not pass anything inside the `post()`

Answer (score 3):

It is unknown if 'disp_ch_ids' could actually ever be "countable", (which in this context means an `array`) but assuming it is, we first need to determine if it has *any* value.

`input::post()` will return `NULL` if `$_POST['disp_ch_ids']` does not exist. But it could be an empty string, or an array with no items.

```
$ch_ids = $this->input->post('disp_ch_ids');

// does $ch_ids contain anything?
if( ! empty($ch_ids))
{
    //but is it "countable"
    if(is_array($ch_ids))
    {
        //OK to count it
        print_r(count($ch_ids));
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($ch_ids);
    }
}
```